# Apply REPLACE function on the source cell itself

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is it possible in Excel to format apply the result of a formula on the cell itself?

I have a cell which containing text. The text starts with an unwanted bullet point and I would like to use the REPLACE function below to remove the leading bullet points.

Consider the cell A2 to be the source which contains the text with the leading special character (bullet), I would like to apply this function on it and want the result text to be pasted back into A2

```
=replace(A2,1,6,””)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use Find and Replace (ctrl+H)?

Comment: Agree with @SJR. But if you want to use VBA for this, capture you range in an array, remove the leading bullet point from each item and then paste the range back into your original range

Comment: So, do you want to replace a string from a cel where a formula exists? Would you like to adapt that formula in order to return something without that specific string to be replaced? Can you better explain what you want? The answer I provided replace what you need from a formula result, but it **replace the formula, too**...

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your cells on a column (5 in example code) contain text like "x 12345", "x 3456", "x abcd" etc. will be transformed in : "12345", "3456", "abcd" etc. You can set `strRepl` to be any string:

```
Sub testReplace()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, colNo As Long, arrCol As Variant
  Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, strRepl
   Set sh = ActiveSheet ' put here your sheet
   colNo = 5 'Column E:E
   strRepl = "x " 'use here your string to be removed
   lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, colNo).End(xlUp).Row
   arrCol = sh.Range(Cells(1, colNo), Cells(lastRow, colNo)).Value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrCol)
        arrCol(i, 1) = Replace(arrCol(i, 1), "x ", "")
   Next i
   sh.Range(Cells(1, colNo), Cells(lastRow, colNo)) = arrCol
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably worth encapsulating `Replace` with a `Trim` to ensure there are no leading or trailing spaces

Comment: @Zac: Good point, I adapted the code to include the space. But he should know what is to be replaced. Maybe he needs some more spaces in the rest of the string...

Comment: Can replace take a start position and end position instead of the actual character. Also, how to apply this function on all the cells of a column?

Comment: I'm confused... Does the code work for active cell, or not? If yes, I will provide the solution for all the column. If not, what "Can replace take a start position and end position instead of the actual character" does mean?

Comment: What do you like to achieve and the sample code does not provide? Can you post a model of the initial string versus what you need? Something like: "x 12345" versus "12345"...

Comment: If you want to get the string from a specific position within the string, use `Mid`